# MVC 3 validation: want to turn my labels red that correspond to controls that failed validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

[image]

I am using MVC 3 validation. My Product Manager wants the label for each control that has an error to turn red.

So 'Student First Name' label should turn red. 'Email address' label should turn red.

I tried to wrap each error msg in a div and check the length of each div

```
<div id="divValStudentFirstName">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.studentFirstName)</div>
```

in a js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($("#divValStudentFirstName").length > 1) {
                ("#divStudentFirstName").css("color", "red");

    }
```

But I have no success. The validation check is done without a complete refresh and as a result, my $(document).ready isn't fired when validation hits.

Comment: Could you show a part of the code of your view ? Are you using LabelFor... for labels, EditorFor for inputs, or ?

Comment: yes Raphael, its a typical implementation


                    <div class="editor-label" id="divStudentFirstName">
                       
                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.studentFirstName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.studentFirstName, new { style = @controlWidth })
                    </div>

with validation grouped in divs above the form

Comment: I placed each ValidationMessageFor in a dedicated named div so i could check if each was populated hoping to use that as a condition to change the css of the div holding the labelfor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Client side validation disabled :

```
public static IHtmlString ValidationLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText = null) {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
            var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            string resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? name.Split('.').Last();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText)) {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }

            var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
            tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name)));
            tag.GenerateId(name);
            tag.SetInnerText(resolvedLabelText);
            ModelState modelState;
            string fullName = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
            if (html.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState)) {
                if (modelState.Errors.Count > 0) {
                    tag.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
                }
            }
            return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString());
        }
```

**EDIT**

Client side validation enabled

I'm really not a king in js, but this seems to work (well on a simple case at least)

```
$('form').submit(function () {
        var form = $(this);
        $('label').removeClass('field-validation-error');
        if (!form.valid()) {
            $('.input-validation-error')
                .each(function () {
                    $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").addClass('field-validation-error');
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: client side validation is enabled. But my requirement is to ALSO make the associated control's label red. I want to add a css attribute with JQuery after the validation message comes up (like in img I uploaded)

Comment: @Dave yes, my remark was stupid. I'm still looking for something ;)

Comment: never stupid. this problem complex. I'm surprised how difficult. I really thought I could just check the error msg on $().ready(). But since the validation seems to be all client side without hitting the server, no refresh happens and no new $ready() event.

Comment: seems like I may have to dig into the jquery libs that do the heavy lifting for razor validation. I hope and pray there's an easier way cause I can't even find a good reference on it.

Comment: cant wait to hear it. I've been banging my head against all kinds of crazy ideas!

Comment: @Dave look at EDIT (it's certainly far far from perfection, but)

Comment: very clever! you're intercepting the trigger and pre-validating. And you already had some success with it? you get my +1 whether it works or not.

Comment: @Dave well, I did this on a sample MvcApplication app (tried on "default" register +logon forms), just adding this in a script tag at the end of the page, and it "looks like it works".

Comment: Nice, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: I had to tweak the code a little but the solution was elegantly smooth and clever. Thanks! I wish I had another +20 to apply!

Comment: @Dave, I'd be interested by your solution, if you can !

Answer (score 0):

Below is a JQuery function that will color the containing div tag by adding (or removing) an error class when the submit button is clicked. It can easily be changed to add the class to the label.

```
 $('form').submit(function () {

    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length == 0) {
                $(this).removeClass('error-colored');
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('error-colored');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution was based on the following tutorial for adding bootstrap error highlighting to MVC validation. It also addresses server side validation errors. http://www.braindonor.net/blog/integrating-bootstrap-error-styling-with-mvcs-unobtrusive-error-validation/381/